# Accessing a private variable from a subclass by a public inherited method

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the following code:

```
public class A {
 private Integer a=7;
 
 public int get_a() {
    return a;
    
 }

}
```

```
public class B extends A{

}
```

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        B obiect1=new B();
       System.out.println( obiect1.get_a());
    
       
    }

}
```

The Variabile "a" is private so will not be inherited by class B, but method "get_a()" is public so it will be inherited by class B. In "main()" method when I call "obiect1.get_a()" what will happen sice class B doesn't have variabile "a"? It will show 7 on console but why? B doesn't inherited variabile "a". What is actually happen

Comment: The private variable _is_ inherited. `B` does have the `a` variable. It's just not directly accessible because it was declared private.

Comment: So simple, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between public, protected, package-private and private in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/what-is-the-difference-between-public-protected-package-private-and-private-in)

Answer (score 0):

With the use of the extends keyword, the subclass B will be able to inherit all the properties of the superclass A except for the private properties of the superclass, but with the help of a public getter, get_a() in this case, it is possible to access variable a from Class A.